# AC circuit containing Capacitor only

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, capacitance

Why does voltage(v) lag by 90 degrees in an AC circuit containing only Capacitor behind the current(I).

Comment: .....Lag *what*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The I-V relationship of a capacitor is

$$I = C\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

And

$$\frac{\rm{d}}{\rm{d}t}\sin\left(\omega t\right)=\omega\cos\left(\omega t\right)$$

And

$$\cos\left(\omega t\right) = \sin\left(\omega t + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$